# gcloud.app.deploy Error Response: [13] Failed to create cloud build: invalid bucket - how to fix?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, gcloud

I figured this out and figured that I'd leave a quick note here since Google turned up *zero* results that helped me :[

After following [Quickstart for Python 3 in the App Engine Standard Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/quickstart#top_of_page), I received an error in the [Deploy and run Hello World on App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/quickstart#deploy_and_run_hello_world_on_app_engine) step.

The error that I got was:
"ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] Failed to create cloud build: invalid bucket "1012918181174.cloudbuild-logs.googleusercontent.com"; builder service account does not have access to the bucket."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this by going to the [Cloud Build Settings page](https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/settings/service-account) for the project I was attempting to deploy, and then enabling the 'App Engine Admin' service.